# Old Books with chord progression charts or matrices?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, harmony, chord-progressions

I've heard that there are old books with chord progression charts that tell you which chords are likely/plausible to come after a given chord. A music teacher said there are charts that can get quite large.

One example I know of is Walter Piston's Harmony book, but the chart in the early chapter was quite small, and very basic/diatonic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about an old chart that shows chord progressions. The ones you might be thinking of are mostly found in new textbooks, like this one from [MusicTheory.net](https://www.musictheory.net/lessons/57):

[image]

But you may be interested in Schoenberg's "Chart of Regions" from his *Structural Functions of Harmony*:

[image]

Here's a smaller, minor version of the chart:

[image]

And here's a colorized version of the original, almost as a type of heatmap:

[image]

---

Keep in mind that the charts will change depending on how "old" you mean. If you're looking for a chart with Roman numerals, for instance, you won't get one until at least the 19th century, since it wasn't until Vogler and Weber came along ca. 1800 and began using Roman-numeral notation.

---

There are other types of geometrical structures that show relationships between chords, like the *[Tonnetz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonnetz)*:

[image]

The triangles create triads; the bold triangle **C E♭ G**, for instance, is a C minor triad. But something like the *Tonnetz* focuses more on *distance between chords* than on actually creating harmonic progressions. But the *Tonnetz* does lead towards something we call neo-Riemannian theory, where the notion of progression (through "transformations" like P, L, and R) is something a bit different:

[image]

Comment: Cool, did Weber or Vogler have charts?

Comment: I know of [at least one](https://thornepalmer.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/tableofkeyrelationships.jpg) from Weber, but again it's less about progressions and more about relationships between keys (not chords). I'm not sure about Vogler.

Comment: What about neo-riemmanian theories?

Comment: Good question; a lot of neo-Riemannian theory is based on the *Tonnetz* at the bottom of my answer; I'll add more right now.

Comment: Awesome. Can I ask where that last chart, and first chart was from?

Comment: It's just a chart someone made, but you can read more about what it means [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Riemannian_theory#Triadic_transformations_and_voice_leading).

Comment: and the very first one?

Comment: I just searched online for "chord progressions chart" :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first one is from https://www.musictheory.net/lessons/57. If it is, can we cite it correctly for future users?

Comment: @Dom Good call; just did!

Comment: The only reason I caught it is because I just used it in the answer I just wrote :).

Comment: I'm glad you did! That link actually doesn't work for me, but it might just be my browser...I'll check it out tomorrow on another computer and update it as needed.