# What does Schoenberg mean by "intermediary region"?

Tags: theory, terminology, modulation

I read this from Arnold Schoenberg's *Preliminary Exercises in Counterpoint*. The original part is: Later, intermediary regions are likewise introduced (Simple Counterpoint in Three Voices, Chapter VIII); "Their purpose is usually that of emphasizing a contrast through their harmonic differences. This is achieved by using the characteristics of these regions more or less as if they themselves were basic tonalities."

Answer (score 8):

From what I can tell, Schoenberg's term here is ambiguous and, honestly, unimportant.

Imagine we're in C major. Now, imagine we modulate to E major. There's occasionally a gray area between the "obviously C major" part and the "obviously E major" part where it's unclear exactly what tonic is. In many cases, composers will hint at keys other than either C or E. These hinted-at keys are the "intermediary regions," so named because they occur between the more important tonalities of (in this case) C and E.

"Intermediary regions" are apparently *not* related to Schoenberg's Chart of Regions that I discuss in my answer to [Old Books with chord progression charts or matrices?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/56661/old-books-with-chord-progression-charts-or-matrices/56662#56662)

(This answer is based off of p. 103 of Dudeque's [Music Theory and Analysis in the Writings of Arnold Schoenberg](https://books.google.com/books?id=_y4rDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=schoenberg%20intermediary%20region&source=bl&ots=W-enpqb8NW&sig=vVYZ7lynmomh-yBCIgfyAQam0Cs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjki4iX0LHWAhVi_4MKHfTUCxAQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=schoenberg%20intermediary%20region&f=false).)